# How can i install Mu micropython editor in ubuntu?

Tags: python, editor

I am developing something on Micro: Bit and I want Mu micro python editor on my Linux machine.Help me out

Thanking you

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy method, I did the following

1) Downloaded the zip file from  https://github.com/mu-editor/mu

2) unzipped it. In a terminal type

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip mu-master.zip
```

3) got the relevant python packages

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

4) Install it with pip3, pip3 doesn't like being ran with sudo

```
cd ~/Downloads/mu-master
sudo su
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
make clean
exit
```

5) all users who use Mu need to be in group dialout

```
sudo usermod -a -Gdialout user-name
```

6) Test it

```
cd ~/Downloads/mu-master
./run.py
```

7) Put it 'live', somewhere on $PATH

```
sudo mv ~/Dowloads/mu-master /usr/local/bin
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s mu-master/run.py Mu
```

I have called the executable Mu as there are other linux programs called mu

8) You also need to do the following

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qsci
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtserialport
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install on 16.0.4  LTS following these instructions from #adafruit

`Mu` require python version 3. If you haven't installed python yet, do so via your command line using something like `sudo apt-get install python3`

You'll also need `pip3` (or `pip` if you only have `python3` installed) - try running `pip3 --version`

If that didn't work, run `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and finally run
`pip3 install mu_editor`
You can now run mu directly from the command line

Followed it exactly type mu as stated from the command line and MU Editor works like a charm.  Hope this helps.